# DB2 Execution via command line

Tags: sql, db2

I am new for DB2, don't have much idea but currently facing a issues, please do share your inputs on my below problem, thanks in advance.

We have a scenario where we are migrating from oracle to db2 , so existing code migration is a critical task, in that we have a scenario where we need to execute a sql files from command prompt with existing oracle command

```
Sqlplus ##@****
```

is command used to then it asked for password : ******

Next step :

```
sqlplus ###@****** @xyz.sql
```

these above steps I need to convert into `db2` execution flow and I am facing issues I tried with

```
db2 connect to Database user XXX using ******
```

facing error : 
    SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.

```
db2 ###@Database @xyz.sql
```

> Error : DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement
>   because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL
>   processing it returned: SQL1024N  A database connection does not
>   exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

I may not framed well but I hope you got my issues please do you suggest and put some valuable comments that will help me solve this issues.

Comment: Unless you live in the nineties and are running Windows 98, there is no DOS anymore. It is not DOS. Stop saying DOS.

Comment: (thanks, horse-with-no-name)

Comment: Thanks Mike , but I guess its not that difficult to understand the problem rather than making comment on that , thanks for your efforts to review that question.

Comment: The DB2 environment doesn't seem to be set for the CLP; try running `db2 connect...` in the "DB2 command window" (if I remember the shortcut name under Windows correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Many companies are moving from Oracle to Db2 and IBM has provided the [CLPPlus command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html) for the purpose of mimicking `sqlplus` features.

It is recommended that in migration scenrios you set up your Db2 database in Oracle compatibility mode. I would suggest that you take a look at this [IBM Redbook that walks you through the steps from Oracle to Db2](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247736.html?Open).